# Commenting Event Handlers params

Tags: actionscript-3, comments

How should I comment an event handler param?
I mean, should I comment event handler param?

Example:

TimerMessage class extends Timer.

TimerMessage class, has a setMessage method, which stores a text message whithin its public
var 'message'.

in usage:

```
var timer_message:TimerMessage = new TimerMessage(1000, 1)
timer_message.setMessage('hello')
timer_message.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, displayMessage)

private function displayMessage(e:TimerEvent):void{
txt.text = e.target.message
e.target.stop()
e.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, displayMessage)
}
```

How should I comment displayMessage handler?

```
/* Displays message on main stage
 * @param e - timer event
 * */
```

Like that?

I think that @param part, is too redundant.

What you think?

Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I fail to see the point in this question. How should you comment the handler? Totally up to you

Comment: Do your self a favor, and read this:http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882  or at least watch Uncle Bob Martin's video cast on names: http://www.cleancoders.com/codecast/clean-code-episode-2/show  You will realize that commenting anything but public API is a waste of time and makes your code *less* readable.

Comment: Interesting, thank you @weltraumpirat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not too redundant. I usually press Command-Shift-D (on Mac, on windows I think you replace Command key with the Control key) before any method or variable that I would like to document.

Flash Builder generates a comment template for you to fill in, including a @param for each argument in the method.

This can be turned into beautiful looking HTML documentation for your code with the [asdoc command](http://www.wastedpotential.com/flash-as3-the-simple-way-to-create-an-api-reference-with-asdoc/). At which point all those redundant @param things seem less redundant, and actually pretty neat. [There are other tags too](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ff6.html).

Comment: In Flash Develop, if you type /** above the method, it will generate the ASDoc template too.